# customize logon or welcome screen in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

There's a specific software that I found before in lifehacker to do this job, but I can't find it anymore. What I want to do is to change the background image of the logon screen on windows 7. Do you know what's that app called.
All I get when I search at google is a registry hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the [**Logon Changer for Windows 7**](http://tweaks.com/software/tweakslogon/)?

[image]

There is another one now: **[Windows 7 Logon Background Changer](http://www.julien-manici.com/windows_7_logon_background_changer/)**

Comment: That was fast :P

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one: [Logon Screen Changer](http://stealth.laurentiu.us/windows7/Logon_Screen_Changer_Windows7.zip)

You can also check this website: http://tweaks.com/software/tweakslogon/